# How can I boot a Surface Pro original with Win 8.1 from a USB device?

Tags: boot, usb

I made the bootable USB Ubuntu, disabled secure boot, shut down, started up holding down the up volume and don't get any option to boot from USB.

What have I missed?

Comment: Is it the original Surface Pro or Surface Pro 2?

Answer (score 2):

- VD = Volume Down
- VU = Volume Up
- PW = Power button

VD, VD+PW, VD: Boot from USB

VU: Enter BIOS

> To boot the Microsoft Surface Pro from USB, shutdown Windows 8 first,
>   then press and hold the Volume Down key, and then press the power
>   button briefly while continuing to hold down the Volume down key.
>
> If you need to change any of the BIOS options then press and hold
>   Volume UP while powering on.

Source: http://youtu.be/2p1UMeqlYSM

Comment: Thanks @Sammy, I must have not paid attention when reading about the volume control. I hold the volume down control while powering on and get the menu, but the only little problem I have then is, there is, there seems to be no onscreen keyboard to hit 'enter' to select the first 'try out' option. :-) is there a way to activate an onscreen keyboard at that time?

Comment: Yeah, you probably thought you have to press "down" volume. When in fact you have to press "down" on volume "up". You have to pay attention. Down and up don't always mean what it says on the button, don't take it literally.

Comment: I know I made the same mistake with my Galaxy S4 phone, where you're supposed to press and hold volume up, home and power button at the same time to enter recovery mode so that I can do a factory restore. I was holding the volume down button... :) So it displayed some nonsense I didn't understand, and there was no menu.

Comment: I don't know what's with the device manufacturers today and their fricking volume button key combos. I can understand it with phones and tablets, as those have limited number of physical buttons. But the Surface Pro is a tablet with keyboard. Which brings us to your issue with the on-screen keyboard. You don't have the keyboard dock? Looks like you will have to buy the Touch Cover or Type Cover to install Linux! That's just sad. :(

Comment: If you can't use the touchscreen to proceed with the Ubuntu Linux installation, then that's a Linux problem. You will probably need some additional drivers or something during installation. You can post a new question about this on the Askubuntu site. Ubuntu might not be the best option for you, other Linux distros might be better suited for touch devices. So you could try another one. Or you might need to specially prep a custom Ubuntu Linux installation image.

Comment: http://www.geek.com/microsoft/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-surface-pro-1539262/

Comment: Looks like WiFi is not working either out of the box. I'm not surprised as Linux seems to have very limited to no WiFi support at all out of the box, you always have to monkey around with it to get things working. You need to grab the Marvell driver first. So it looks like a specially prepped Ubuntu Linux image for Surface Pro is the best way to go. That's of course a much more involved process, but once you get it right, and you boot off of it everything should work straight away.

Comment: That's right, I didn't buy the keyboard dock accessory and I cannot see anywhere onscreen to activate an on-screen keyboard. Thanks very much. I'll look into another distro.